# Asking question about an answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, answers

What if you accept an answer to a question of yours, but you're still left with a question about **that** answer?

The last few questions I posted on Stack Overflow have been about SQL. The last question that got answered sprouted a new problem which needs solving.

Is it ok to post a new question about this? I would have to repost al the example data, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a clarification of the answer, just add a comment.

If it's a completely new question, *ask* a completely new question. You may also want to add a comment to the "old" answer to suggest that the answerer may be interested in the new question too.

Comment: And refer to the previous answer as well in your new question, eventually.

Comment: Ok, that's how I'll handle it from now on. Thank you.

Comment: I don't have commenting privileges at Stack Overflow yet, and I need clarification of an answer there. What is the proper procedure in this case?

Comment: @dog44wgm: Personally I'd probably spend 10 minutes finding a question to answer just to get a couple of upvotes, at which point you can comment. I agree it's a bit of a pain, but getting to 15 rep or whatever is required shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thanks. After much fruitless searching for the answers to that and similar questions, and after some thought, I agree that "build your rep" is the sensible approach.